# How to get AgentId requested from ChasitorInit API in Apex?

Tags: apex, rest-api, chat

I am trying to get agentId which is a property of ChasitorInit it was initiated from LiveAgent session. I have to use Omnichannel flow and apex for other custom route logic. So I have to get agentId in apex too. If it is not possible I will try to add pre-chat-entry for agentId at the LiveAgent and then I will take it from ConversionContextEntry. Thanks.[ChasitorInit](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.live_agent_rest.meta/live_agent_rest/live_agent_rest_request_bodies.htm#ChasitorInit)